# Use Webpack to output es6?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to use Webpack to bundle all the JavaScript files and output the resulting bundle.js as an es6 file, and not to es5? So, it is Webpack's job to bundle, but is it actually Webpack's job to convert to es6? Or is that the job of some Webpack loader? Or would I have to use babel for that?

Comment: You’ll need to use Babel or another transpiler to compile ES2015 to ES5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack still can't do this.
There is an open ticket here
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933

For now, if you want to bundle es6 the most promising solution seems to be [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en)

This article is also linked in the discussion on GitHub and provides a pretty good overview

https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c

Comment: What? Webpack has been able to do this for years. Or am I missing something? I'm generating both es5 and es6 in one run

Comment: @MathijsSegers I was only able to get es6 output from webpack when I added a plugin someone has built to achieve it. I'm not aware of this feature in webpack. Rollup still isn't working for me, either.

Comment: @MathijsSegers Can you please show me the way to "easily configure it to output es6"?

Comment: It depends on your setup, the issue linked by lukas seems to be about the internals of webpack, not your codebase itself, since webpack's default is to provide it as is. Of course if you use typescript you need something to convert it to javascript, or you can use a library like babel to transpile to es5 or a certain set of es6 etc. 

By default webpack does not do anything to your code, that must be something you or your team configured

Comment: @MathijsSegers I am struggling to achive what you say. It always throws `export 'default' was not found in <module name>` error when you use your module. It looks like webpack cannot output valid ES6 module.

Comment: Or you try to use a default export and have none defined. This all depends on your loaders and configuration, I can't help you with your issue but you could get help opening a new issue with your current setup, or even an example repo.

Answer (score 9):

webpack 5 can generate both ES5 and ES6/ES2015 code.

The default configuration will generate ES2015. If you need to support older browsers (like IE11), you can set `output.ecmaVersion: 5`.

https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#turn-off-es2015-syntax-in-runtime-code-if-necessary

Comment: From what I just saw on https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#turn-off-es2015-syntax-in-runtime-code-if-necessary, it is recommended to use `target: ['web', 'es5']` to support older browsers like IE11.

Comment: This was definitely mentioned somewhere in the Webpack 5 transition but I can't find `ecmaVersion` in the docs anywhere anymore.

Comment: Looking for `output.environment` instead of `output.ecmaVersion`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/