# How to build a component library using TypeScript, Ant Design and Rollup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, rollup

I'm trying to create an example boilerplate for a library of reusable components in TypeScript, using Ant Design for UI elements and Rollup for bundling.

The [Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-in-typescript) although useful, doesn't give specific details for configuring Rollup and I've not had any luck finding an example using the same technology stack.

Using information from various online sources I've put together an outline boilerplate and published it to the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MrStevenHill/rollup-antd-library-typescript)

However, the build output is showing a number of warnings from Rollup relating to rewriting references to 'this'. Can anyone suggest changes to my build config to resolve this issue?

```
(!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules\antd\es\affix\index.js
 6: import _inherits from "babel-runtime/helpers/inherits";
 7: import _typeof from "babel-runtime/helpers/typeof";
 8: var __decorate = this && this.__decorate || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
                     ^
 9:     var c = arguments.length,
10:         r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc,
...
```

Comment: Please include the *relevant* parts of your code in the question

Comment: Improved the question and trimmed the error logs. Please let me know if there are any further changes which you would like to see.

Comment: Thanks for posting the repository.  I spent some time trying to get your project to work and made progress but got discouraged by Rollup's requirement that the exports of each module be specified in the configuration file if they can't be detected automatically (see [this issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/211)).  Why do you want to use Rollup?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look at this. Probably worth saying that I'm not opposed to other bundling solutions (e.g. webpack) but Rollup seems to be the preferred option for building libraries of reusable components.

Comment: To make a stronger case for Rollup, a key requirement is to enable tree shaking of unused components. This requires ES6 (ES2015) modules [link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). Rollup produces ES6 modules by default. Webpack is unable to output ES6 currently. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058680/use-webpack-to-output-es6)

Comment: @Steve any update on this?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili sorry the answer was deleted. Added it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolve by updating the rollup config to mark the antd dependencies as external using rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external

The updated code can be seen in the [Repo on GitHub](https://github.com/MrStevenHill/rollup-antd-library-typescript)

Comment: thanks so much @steve. one more issue now is that antd styles are not loading , do you happen to face same issue?

Comment: Hi @BehnamEsmaili. Just checked and I'm seeing the same issue. To be honest I've abandoned trying to use Ant Design in this way, in favour of building a bespoke UI library using Styled Components. If you manage to make any progress would be happy to hear about it though.

Comment: github link is dead

Answer (score 1):

@Steve, I don't know if you already solved this problem, but I found a solution that worked for me using `rollup-plugin-babel`:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url';

import pkg from './package.json';

const antdVars = require('./src/antd-vars');

export default {
    input: 'src/index.tsx',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: 'cjs',
            exports: 'named',
            sourcemap: true,
        },
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'es',
            exports: 'named',
            sourcemap: true,
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        url(),
        nodeResolve({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        }),
        typescript({
            exclude: ['*.d.ts', '**/*.d.ts', '**/*.story.tsx', '**/*.spec.tsx'],
            rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
            clean: true,
        }),
        babel({
            babelrc: false,
            plugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }]],
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            exclude: /\**node_modules\**/,
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: /\**node_modules\**/,
        }),
        postcss({
            extensions: ['.css', '.scss', '.less'],
            use: ['sass', ['less', { javascriptEnabled: true, modifyVars: antdVars }]],
        }),
    ],
};
```