# How to use antd as a base library for creating custom library using rollup?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd, rollup

I am creating a custom forms library in react with rollup on the top of antd components for internal use.
but i didn't found any useful information on how to bundle the ant components in rollup.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? have you looked at the below?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338345/how-to-build-a-component-library-using-typescript-ant-design-and-rollup